# Mips Function Calling

Tags: function, loops, mips

```
msg4: .asciiz "\nAverage is: "
      main

jal AverageFunction
la $a0, msg4 
li $v0, 4
syscall
move $a0, $t
li  $v0, 1
syscall

    sumfunction:

la $t3, array 
sum:
bge $t4, $t1, done 
lw $t0, 0($t3)  
add $t5, $t5, $t0 
addi $t3, $t3, 4 
addi $t4, $t4, 1 
b sum 
done:
jr $ra

AverageFunction:
    jal sumfunction
    div $t6, $t5, $t1
    jr $ra
```

nothing prints when I run this program. I need to call function from another function and return to main-------------

Answer (score 1):

When `AverageFunction` calls `sumfunction` it overwrites `$ra` with the new return address (i.e. the address of the instruction following `jal sumfunction`). Therefore when `AverageFunction` tries to return, it ends up in an infinite loop.

You need to save the old return address somehow, and then restore it. One way would be to use the stack:

```
AverageFunction:
  addi $sp,$sp,-4    # "push" operations pre-decrement the stack pointer  
  sw $ra,($sp)       # Save the current return address on the stack

  jal sumfunction
  div $t6, $t5, $t1

  lw $ra, ($sp)      # Restore the old return address
  addi $sp,$sp,4     # "pop" operations post-increment the stack pointer
  jr $ra
```